# McGill Style for Legal Citation for Latex

Tags: bibtex, citing, legal-style

I was curious if there was a style package for the Canadian Guide to Uniform Legal Citation, 7th Edition, or affectionally known as the McGill citation style?

I found LawTex, however it uses the bluebook style.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Legal citation styles are quite a challenge. If you are willing to use `biblatex` you could have a look at [`oscola`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/oscola) and modify it to your needs.

Comment: A link to the citation is here. http://library.queensu.ca/law/lederman/legalcitation

Comment: Also I may look into modifying oscola. Thank you.

Comment: I have started to develop a McGill style for biblatex. It is very preliminary, and will, I fear, only be developed to accommodate my immediate needs. But I am happy to share the load if you (or others) are interested in contributing.

Comment: @jon I am interested to contribute, I need this for a project. Where can I see the actual work?

Answer (score 1):

A nice easy way to create custom bibliography styles is through the command:

```
latex makebst
```

This will ask you lots of questions and walk you through the creation of a new bibtex style file, which you can then use to make your bibliography.

Comment: Unfortunately legal citations are a whole other domain for which `makebst` is not equipped.