# Is there a citation style for the "Canadian Guide to Uniform Legal Citation" aka McGill Guide?

Tags: citing, legal-style

I have searched for answers, and it appears that there *is* a version of the McGill Guide legal citation format around but it hasn't been released generally.

Does anyone know if there are plans to release this generally or if there is an alternative I can use to cite legal sources such as Canadian case law, journal articles, and Canadian legislation?

I'm fairly new to TeX and am using MiKTeX along with TeXworks. I have figured out all of the basic features that I need, but the last piece of the puzzle is the citation format.

Note that I would not need to create a bibliography with this style, only footnotes (*supra* and *ibid* for already-cited sources are also a must). I have found the LawTeX project and this would be perfect for me if I could cite in the Bluebook format, but unfortunately McGill style is required for my project.

Comment: No. I would be very interested in such a format, however. If time were not such a pressing concern, I would've started to work on implementing it in `biblatex` (which really is what is needed for such a complex style). Where is this unreleased format, and to which version of *McGill* does it conform? FYI: there is a [`.csl` implementation](https://www.zotero.org/styles), which means (in theory), you can write in `markdown` and convert to LaTeX (and other formats) using [`pandoc`](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/). But, for complex documents, I find `markdown` insufficient....

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132153/mcgill-style-for-legal-citation-for-latex which doesn't have a good answer, but there is apparently the start of a bibtex style here http://osdir.com/ml/tex.bibtex.jurabib.user/2006-11/msg00011.html

Comment: When I said that there was a version of the McGill format that hadn't been released, I was referring to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71306/bluebook-support-in-latex/71316#71316, where @paulstanley said: "I don't know of any Bluebook style, and I think I would if it existed. Given the notorious complexities of the Bluebook it would have to be a biblatex project, and it would be quite a project! In the common law world, I know there is a written-and-working-but-unreleased version of the McGill style for Canadian authorities..." That post was in September 2012.

Comment: I have started to develop a McGill style for `biblatex`. It is very preliminary, and will, I fear, only be developed to accommodate my immediate needs. But I am happy to share the load if you (or others) are interested in contributing.

Comment: @jon I am interested to contribute, I need this for a project. Where can I see the actual work?